# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: blockchain, contract-deployment

Here's my code for deploying a mock contract :

```
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains } = require("../helper-hardhat-config")

const BASE_FEE = "250000000000000000" //ethers.utils.parseEther("0.25") 
const GAS_PRICE_LINK = 1e9 // 1000000000

module.exports = async function ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    // const args = [BASE_FEE, GAS_PRICE_LINK]

    if (chainId == 31337) {
        log("Local network detected! Deploying Mock...")
    }
 
    await deploy("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock", {
        from: deployer,
        log: true,
        args: [BASE_FEE, GAS_PRICE_LINK],
    })
    log("MOCK DEPOYED......!")
    log("------------------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "mocks"]
```

And Here's the error:

```
   Error: ERROR processing /home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/deploy/00-deploy-mocks.js:
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
        at getFrom (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:1713:14)
        at _deploy (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:533:9)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at _deployOne (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/helpers.ts:1004:16)
        at Object.module.exports [as func] (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/deploy/00-deploy-mocks.js:17:5)
        at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1219:22)
        at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1052:5)
        at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:438:5)
        at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:308:14)
        at Environment.run (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:156:14)
        at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1222:19)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:1052:5)
        at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:438:5)
        at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:308:14)
        at Environment.run (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:156:14)
        at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:584:32)
        at Environment._runTaskDefinition (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:308:14)
        at Environment.run (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/runtime-environment.ts:156:14)
        at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (/home/arpit/hh-fcc/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/index.ts:669:5)
    error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

GitHub repo for this project:  [https://github.com/Arpit7707/hardhat-raffle-fcc]

Answer (score 1):

I'm following the same tutorial and had the same issue.

You can solve the problem by adding `await` before the `getNamedAccounts()` because it's an async function.

This will allow the `getNamedAccounts()` function to finish executing before proceeding to the next line of code.

Change this:

```
 const { deployer } = getNamedAccounts()
```

to

```
 const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
```

Hope it helps!